# Abstract Factory Pattern and Multi-Level factory w/ factory in product

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, abstract

i implemented an abstract factory pattern, but i am facing a situation where i would need my product to also be a Factory Manager.

What i mean is that some of my product can also be parents of other product, like it is in many situation.

Lets say i have a Company, which also have Employees(person), and that we can take notes about the company, the person, or whatever. Then it would look like this:

Client -> CompanyFactory -> Company Product -> PersonFactory -> Person Product -> NoteFactory -> Note Product, etc...

Would it be a bad practice to have a product be a manager of factories and maintain collections of other product using the Abstract Factory Pattern in a somewhat complex hierarchy?

Why am i trying to implement this pattern is to help our development team, hide implementation, set rules and avoid big ball of Spaghetti code as much as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might consider it no good practice to try implementing everything using some design patterns just for the sake of it. Quite often a simple and non-generic solution for the specific problem at hand can be a much better fit.

Don't get me wrong, the Gang of Four patterns among many others are great and really useful. But not as general building blocks for everything.

*Concerning your comment:* This is a great and worthwhile effort and I appreciate your intentions. Still, focusing on desing patterns instead of the specific problem often leads to a different type of pasta:  **Lasagna code**, where you have layer of abstraction upon layer of abstraction just to replace what previously was just a few lines of code. Nothing against patterns or abstraction, but everything can easily be overdone.

Comment: Why am i trying to implement this pattern is to help our development team, hide implementation, set rules and avoid big ball of Spaghetti code as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not trying to be overkill, just adding some layer of abstraction as you said. I'll consider this question closed, thanks!